What is a "CFG" reference designator and these components with "O" label?
I have a PCB with burnt component, which is numbered as CFGx and there is an "O" on the component:

I looked up but was not able to find anything. It might be configuration related and not specific for the type of the component. There are exposed pads with no component with a similar numbering:

I wonder what the components in the original image are. I suspect that they are fuses with 0 ohms.

Do Help identifying an SMD component and What is the usage of Zero Ohm & MiliOhm Resistor? help?

It was in a device, where I misconnected (same connected different parts) something. Some other component was on this line. I think that the current was too high on the component and the component burnt.

@SarenTasciyan Any component can be a fuse if you put enough current through it, though often not a very good fuse.

I think in this particular case it worked. I later found out that a single "0" means not a very good 0 ohm resistor. Perhaps, that's why this blew up before other things such as traces.

They are 0Ω "resistors" (same form factor as regular resistors but very low resistance). They are not fuses. It's a '0' rather than an 'O'.
CFG stands for "configuration". They are jumpers used for some kind of configuration (by their presence or absence some selection is made).
Here is a datasheet from resistor maker Yageo. You can see the jumper specifications such as maximum 50mΩ resistance and maximum allowable current.
